# coldfusion ftpsclient storefile

Tags: coldfusion, ftp, ftps

i am using ftpsclient for ftp file transfer , as it is explicit tls

here's the code i am using :

```
<cfscript>
ftpsClient = CreateObject("java","org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient").init(JavaCast("boolean",false));

ftpsClient.connect(JavaCast("string","test.hostedftp.com"),21);
connected = ftpsClient.isConnected();

WriteOutput("Is Connected:" &  connected & '<br/>');

reply = ftpsClient.getReplyCode();
WriteOutput("Is reply:" &  reply & '<br/>');

login = ftpsClient.login('test','test');
WriteOutput("Is Logged in:" &  login & '<br/>');

    ftpsClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpsClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/test");
    reply = ftpsClient.getReplyCode();
    WriteOutput("Is changeWorkingDirectory:" &  reply & '<br/>');


</cfscript>


<cfset fileStream = CreateObject(
            "java",
            "java.io.FileInputStream"
            ).Init(
                CreateObject(
                    "java",
                    "java.io.File"
                    ).Init(
                        "C:\Users\test\test.txt"
                        )
            ) />
                <cfset storefile = ftpsClient.storeFile("LocalFile.txt", fileStream)>
                <cfset replycode = ftpsClient.getReplyCode()>
                <cfoutput>#replycode#</cfoutput><br>
                <cfset fileStream.close()>
                <cfoutput>#storefile#</cfoutput>
```

But its not uploading the file here' the output :

```
Is Connected:YES
Is reply:234
Is Logged in:YES
Is changeWorkingDirectory:250
500
NO
```

which means after storefie replycode is coming out to be "500".

I dont know what's wrong in the code, if anybody can help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That looks like `500 internal server error.`

Comment: yes but the file ""C:\Users\test\test.txt"" is there .

Comment: and 500 stands for "Syntax error, command unrecognized and the requested action did not take place. This may include errors such as command line too long." in ftp return code lists.

Comment: Well, that's a good clue.  Have you checked your commands to make sure they are valid?

Comment: yeah i checked , here's the link i am referring though http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#line.2974

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using cfftp?

Comment: yeah , because its explicit tls ftp , and cfftp doesn't work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the PROT command.  You can put it after the  enterLocalPassiveMode() line

```
ftpsClient.execPROT("P");
```

I was able to get it to work in my local testing this way.

PROT deals with Data Protection Level.  If one isnt supplied, it sends it as Clear.  P stands for Private.  Im guessing it is transferring the file not securely.

What does the getReplyString() display?   Does it say anything about the Data channel not being secure?